# Converting numeric/character column to date format in R

Tags: r

I have a date column in my data set which is not in the correct format and looks like this "825" which means 25 August. Now i need to create a new column which takes the date column as input and return me whether its a weekday or a weekend but firstly i would have to convert it into the proper format.

All dates are from 2017.

Comment: Is "121" January 21st or December 1st?

Comment: Its January 21st.

Comment: Why not December? There is no way we could know this when you don't post your data.

Comment: There was initially a "0" before the number, but it got removed as it is numeric. For December 1st, it is 1201.

Comment: @Ashish can you start from the non-numeric version?

Comment: Please provide a small subset of your data - just enough for us to work on. If the values get truncated, read in the data as character and the leading zero should be preserved. If you're using `read.table`, see `colClasses` argument name.

Comment: @Barbara yes we can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you can start from the non-numeric version of the column (so, maintaining the 0), a possible solution is this:

```
x <- "0825"
x <- paste(x, "2017", sep ="")
y<- as.Date(as.character(x), "%m%d%Y")
wd <- weekdays(y)
```

**EDIT**: edited to add the code for the weekdays.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Barbara

Comment: @Ashish I have now added also the code to add the weekdays

Answer (score 0):

Consider this dummy example:

```
df <- data.frame(orig = c("821", "1201", "121", "111", "222"))
# orig
# 821
# 1201
# 121
# 111
# 222

# Convert it to date
library(lubridate)
df$date <- ymd(paste("2017", gsub("(..)$", " \\1", df$orig)))
# orig       date
# 821  2017-08-21
# 1201 2017-12-01
# 121  2017-01-21
# 111  2017-01-11
# 222  2017-02-22

# Extract day and define if it's weekend
df$day <- format(df$date, "%a")
df$weekend <- ifelse(df$day %in% c("Sat", "Sum"), TRUE, FALSE)
# orig       date day weekend
# 821  2017-08-21 Mon   FALSE
# 1201 2017-12-01 Fri   FALSE
# 121  2017-01-21 Sat    TRUE
# 111  2017-01-11 Wed   FALSE
# 222  2017-02-22 Wed   FALSE
```

Comment: Yes It did. Thank you.